# Ruby: where does ruby log its errors (location of errors / exceptions)?

Tags: ruby

I have a simple `ruby` script which prints a exception message when something goes wrong.

i am unable to find where the logs are stored to check this.

any help on this would be really great.

Thanks.

Comment: A Ruby script would write errors to STDERR. If you haven't told the script that you want to set STDERR to a file or if you haven't redirect STDERR to a file in the command line then the error would only be written to the concole.

Comment: Errors are written wherever you tell them to be. There is no automatic centralised file that keeps a copy of everything you print to the terminal. If you want to explicitly log errors into a logfile, then update the code to write to a logfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no log files. When errors occur, the Ruby standard library will write its messages to the standard error stream. You can redirect this to a file if you'd like.

Of course, you can do whatever you want in your own code. It's absolutely possible to open a file and log messages to it. There are many logging libraries that provide this functionality.